Adding messages to thread/run using openai-php/client, but not getting a response message
I've got an endpoint, which is supposed to post a message to the OpenAI API and display the response.  I'm using https://github.com/openai-php/client
The code looks something like this (trimmed for brevity):
$client = OpenAI::client($OpenaiApiKey);

$message = $client->threads()->messages()->create($threadId, [
    'role' => 'user',
    'content' => "Option $optionId",
]);

$run = $client->threads()->runs()->retrieve(
    threadId: $threadId,
    runId: $runId,
);

while ($run->status != 'completed') {
    sleep(1);
    $run = $client->threads()->runs()->retrieve($threadId, $runId);

    if($run->status == 'failed') {
        echo json_encode(array('status' => 'failed', 'error' => $run->lastError));
        exit;
    }

    if(++$retries > 20) {
        echo json_encode(array('status' => 'failed', 'error' => 'Timeout waiting for response'));
        exit;
    }
}

$allMessages = $client->threads()->messages()->list($threadId, [
]);

print_r($allmessages);

The list of messages this prints has my message to the API, but no response.  If I try running this endpoint multiple times, I get multiple copies of my message in the thread, but no response to any of the messages.
Why aren't my messages being responded to?  I've used the Assistant I'm using for the responses in the Playground and it always responds to the "Option" text prompts.

I am working in something like this, I realized you never "created" a run, you just retrieve a previous one. And also your code helped me to solve my thing.
$message = $client->threads()->messages()->create(

    $threadId,
    [
        "role" => "user",
        "content" => $message
    ]
);

$run = $client->threads()->runs()->create($threadId, [
    "assistant_id" => $assistant_id,
]);

So your code is actually fine, it was just one annoying function.
